# Alternative to "DropDownWidth" Property for Combo Box in wpf

Tags: wpf

I am unable to locate a property similar to WindowsForm "DropDownWidth" Property for the Combo Box in WPF. Is there a work around to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember if there is such property in a combobox, but you always can alter a default control template. In your case you should specify a width property of a popup element in a control template. Here is a sample code, taken from one of the WPF themes from [Codeplex](http://wpfthemes.codeplex.com/):

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
   ...
      <Popup ... Width="100" >
   ...
 </ControlTemplate>
```

This is a general idea. You can look in a themes source code fore more information. This MSDN pages can also be helpful:

- [Customizing the Appearance of an Existing Control by Creating a ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230084.aspx)
- [ComboBox Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx)
- [Control Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx)

Comment: I tried the following but it did not work.
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="popupTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Popup Width="10000" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

I also tried the ControlTemplate part in my combobox xaml but it did not work. Do you have any working code with you or anything similar??

Comment: You can search for an example inside a theme file (from codeplex). It is just too big to paste here, just open a theme file, for example BureauBlue.xaml, and search for this line: <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">

Comment: And instead of copying the complete control template (which results in a lot of duplicate code, right?), you could also derive a subclass from `ComboBox`, override `OnApplyTemplate`, retrieve the `Popup` instance named `PART_Popup` and set its `Width` property to what you need while leaving everything else up to whoever is templating your comboboxes.